# Select all checkbox in Gridview takes long time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, datagridview

I am working on an application which have a Datagridview with one column of type check box. one more check box is there which toggles the selected rows of a grid-view (selects/deselects the check boxes ).

Here is the code which I am using to implement the above logic.

```
    private void gvBankUnrencolised_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled();
        gvBankUnrencolised.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

private void gvBankUnrencolised_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled();
    string id = null;
    //   gvBankUnrencolised.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    int sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < gvBankUnrencolised.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            //gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            id = id + gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + ",";
            Int32 amt = Convert.ToInt32(gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells["AMT_WITH_SIGN"].Va

            sum = sum + amt;

        }
        else
        {
            //gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
    if (id == null)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected");
    }
    else if (id != null)
    {
        id = id.Remove(id.Length - 1);
    }
    lblVmTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    //lblVmTotal.Text = id;
    Bankid = id;

private void gvBankUnrencolised_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled();
    string id = null;
    //   gvBankUnrencolised.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    int sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < gvBankUnrencolised.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            //gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            id = id + gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + ",";
            Int32 amt = Convert.ToInt32(gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].Cells["AMT_WITH_SIGN"].Value);

            sum = sum + amt;

        }
        else
        {
            //gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
    if (id == null)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected");
    }
    else if (id != null)
    {
        id = id.Remove(id.Length - 1);
    }
    lblVmTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    //lblVmTotal.Text = id;
    Bankid = id;
}

private void selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvBankUnrencolised.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
            row.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

The code works fine when the data is small (500 rows) but as the data grow (>1000) rows the application hangs. is there a way to do this?

EDIT

here is the code which selects all the columns and need to be optimized. I somehow left this important piece of information

```
private void chkBankCheckAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gvBankUnrencolised.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (chkBankCheckAll.Checked == true)
                {
                    gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = true;
                }
                if (chkBankCheckAll.Checked == false)
                {
                gvBankUnrencolised.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why not use JavaScript on client side? Anyway having over 1000 rows on a single page is not a good idea. May be you should either use some kind of pagination or filter your data based on some search query. You are transmitting large amount of data for a single view which also makes it slow both on server side and client side as well.

Comment: @ankit is this regarding WinForms application or asp.net application ? I believe it is Winforms..

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am working on winforms and not asp.net so the performance is not an issue.

Comment: yes it is a winform application.

Comment: I have re-tagged this question to winforms as [DataGridViewDataErrorContexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerrorcontexts.aspx) used in code sample is for Windows applications. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to me change your code to execute selection logic for the cell whose content click is triggered instead of all the rows in the DataGridView control..

### Code

```
private void gvBankUnrencolised_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled(e);
    gvBankUnrencolised.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

// Some other code snippets 

private void selectCells_gvBankUnreconciled()
{
    object cellValue = gvBankUnreconciled.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    if (celValue is DBNull) { return; }

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(cellValue) == true)
            gvBankUnreconciled.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: I left a piece of information. The code that selects all the rows. Which needs to be optimized. Can you please give it a look now.